# How did Dom arrange the meeting with Magdalene Shaw?

Tags: plot-explanation, fast-and-furious-franchise, the-fate-of-the-furious

In *Fate of the Furious*, Dominic Toretto takes advantage of a blind spot in the cameras controlled by Cipher to meet Magdalene Shaw.

How did he arrange the meeting with her? Throughout the movie (if we discount the very first scenes), he was always either on Cipher's plane or behind the wheel of his car, which had a camera. When did he contact her without being noticed?

Comment: Dom tells Cipher that she lost the second she disturbed his honeymoon. It seems it was set up between their meeting in Cuba and his joining...

Comment: @Mennyg Interesting theory, but I'm not fully convinced. After he joined Cipher, she brought him to New York, and he couldn't possibly know that immediately after meeting her in Cuba (or could he?). So maybe there's something else. Anyway, feel free to make that an answer.

Comment: @Mennyg The "Cuba-Theory" is good, however at that time Shaw was still in prison (both of them), so Dom had no idea he would break out and join the team. I also find it very unlikely that putting Hobbs into prison and then Hobbs and Shaw breaking out, was planned from the beginning by Dom and Mr. Nobody, cause that would mean Mr. Nobody knew the whole time what was going on.

Comment: At least it wan't a 20-mile runway.

Comment: I'm guessing he used the same mode of communication as the Avengers in the 2012 movie's finale to talk quietly to each other while being in different parts of the city without any devices or even headsets.
I believe it's called "If The Action's Fast Enough Nobody Will Notice" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing whilst watching the movie.

I have a theory; maybe he had another tracking device on him and gave the tracker to Magdalene Shaw in an emergency, private meeting in Cuba. He might've been able to communicate with her somehow by pressing a button or something on the tracking device that may have signaled her to meet him (knowing his exact location she meets him at the restaurant/bar), or maybe he somehow relays his coordinates of where he was going to head to her.

(or) The tracking device could've also been in his car and pressing the red button(the one he uses to make it look like his vehicle needed repair) may have also signaled the van driver to block the camera angle and to Magdalene Shaw that he was going to meet with her there, at that time- he gives her the tracking device to give to one of his team mates- as he finds out during that meeting that Cipher had put the Shaw family through hell, he knew that they want revenge and must've known that Deckard would be up for it. Therefore his master plan had fallen into place.